# how to disable command name in repeater after 3 items

Tags: asp.net

how to disable command name Show(linkbutton) in repeater after 3 items

Topic   Set Status      Show(linkbutton)

Math    1   seen        show

Math    2   seen        show

Math    3   seen        show

Math    4   Not
Math    5   Not
Math    6   Not

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `Container.ItemIndex` to check if it are the first three items and set the `Visibility` accordingly.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Visible='<%# Container.ItemIndex < 3 %>'><%# Eval("myValue") %></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Thanks,
But I want to do same think by code behind on condition.